# php file upload move_uploaded_file() Failed to open stream

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a file upload script:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["picture"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["picture"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["picture"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["picture"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["picture"]["type"] == "image/png")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)):
    if($_FILES["picture"]["error"] > 0):
        echo "Error: " . $_Files["picture"]["error"];
    else:
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], "/TnA/ProfilePics/" . $_SESSION['ID'] . "." . $extension);
    endif;
endif;
```

But I am getting the errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(TnA/ProfilePics/1.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/91/9848191/html/TnA/webservice.php on line 1067

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/php5nOdhI' to 'TnA/ProfilePics/1.jpg' in /home/content/91/9848191/html/TnA/webservice.php on line 1067
```

Here is my file structure:

```
Web Host Root (I have another site here)
    -TnA (Root of this site)
        -index.html
        -webservice.php
        -ProfilePics
            -(My target location)
```

What relative directory url should I be using? I have tried `ProfilePics/1.jpg` and `/ProfilePics/1.jpg` both result in the same error.

**EDIT:**

Using:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], dirname(__FILE__) . "ProfilePics/" . $_SESSION['ID'] . "." . $extension);
```

I get:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/content/91/9848191/html/TnA/ProfilePics/1.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/91/9848191/html/TnA/webservice.php on line 1067
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely that you have problem using relevant paths. If your upload script is webservice.php then you are actually trying to put file into 
 / %webHostRoot% / **TnA** / **TnA** / ProfilePics / 
directory. Use full path in `move_uploaded_file()`'s target.
Try to use something like:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], dirname(__FILE__)."ProfilePics/" . $_SESSION['ID'] . "." . $extension);
```

UPD:
Here's func to create dirs recursively:

```
function MkDirTree($path,$permissions = 0755, $compat_mode=true) {
    if (!$compat_mode) {
        $dirs = split("/",$path);
        $path = "";
        foreach ($dirs as $key=>$dir) {
            $path .= $dir."/";
            if ($dir!="" && !is_dir($path)) exec("mkdir -m ".$permissions." ".$path);
        }
    } else {
        $dirs = split("/",$path);
        $path = "";
        foreach ($dirs as $key=>$dir) {
            $path .= $dir."/";
            if ($dir!="" && !file_exists($path)) mkdir($path, $permissions);
        }
    }
    return file_exists($path);
}
```

Comment: If I use the full http:// address I get `Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://****.net/TnA/ProfilePics/1.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/content/91/9848191/html/TnA/webservice.php on line 1067`

Comment: You should use **server's** internal absolute path, not your website's URL.
I've edited my answer with the code example.

Comment: Ok, I got it... Somehow my FTP did not create the directory `ProfilePics`. So obviously... it didn't exist. It's fixed now, but your answer did help! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome!
I added a little function to my answer, allowing to create dirs recursively. Hope it'll be useful for you. Good luck!